# ASP.NET - AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() - Assemblies missing after AppDomain restart

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reflection, assemblies

I have a Bootstrapper that looks through all Assemblies in an ASP.NET MVC application to find types that implement an `IBootstrapperTask` interface, and then registers them with an IOC Contrainer. The idea is that you can literaly place your IBootstrapperTasks anywhere, and organise your Projects how you please.

Code for Bootstrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper
{
    static Bootstrapper()
    {
        Type bootStrapperType = typeof(IBootstrapperTask);

        IList<Assembly> assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        List<Type> tasks = new List<Type>();

        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
        {
            var types = from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                        where bootStrapperType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
                            && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract
                        select t;

            tasks.AddRange(types);
        }

        foreach (Type task in tasks)
        {
            if (!IocHelper.Container().Kernel.HasComponent(task.FullName))
            {
                IocHelper.Container().AddComponentLifeStyle(
                    task.FullName, task, LifestyleType.Transient);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Run()
    {
        // Get all registered IBootstrapperTasks, call Execute() method
    }
}
```

After a full build, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` returns all Assemblies in my solution (including all the GAC one's but that doesn't bother me).

However, if the AppDomain is restarted, or I 'bounce' the Web.Config file (adding a space and saving), the static constructor is run again but when `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` is called, **most of the Assemblies are missing**, including the one containing my IBootstrapperTask types.

How do I get around this problem? I guess I could System.IO the /bin directory and load all the DLLs in there manually, but would rather avoid this if possible, or is that the only way? Am I taking the right general approach to this?

This is an ASP.NET MVC 2.0 application running on .NET 4.0, I get this problem with the built-in Visual Studio 2010 Cassini web server, and with IIS7.0 in Integrated Pipeline Mode on Windows Server 2008.

---

**Edit:** I just came across this SO post [Difference between AppDomain.GetAssemblies and BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477787/difference-between-appdomain-getassemblies-and-buildmanager-getreferencedassembli) which says the AppDomain only loads the Assemblies as they're needed (eg. when a method/class from that Assembly is first called). I guess that would explain why the Assemblies are missing on `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` as the Bootstrapper is run very early on.

I noticed if I placed a call to 'something' from the missing Assembly before the Bootstrapper eg:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        MyApp.MissingAssembly.SomeClass someClass =
            new MyApp.MissingAssembly.SomeClass();

        Bootstrapper.Run();
    }
}
```

...it seems to fix the problem, but it is a bit of a hack.

Comment: Nice question and answer!  Took a tour of you blog - you write some good stuff.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I looked through the ASP.NET MVC 2.0 source code and looked up how `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` is implemented. This line is usually put into the Global.asax Application_Start() method and internally it scans all Assemblies for types that implement the AreaRegistration abstract type. This is kinda the behaviour I'm after.

It appears RegisterAllAreas() makes a call to `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()`, well if it's good enough for MVC then it's good enough for me :-)

I've done some experimentation and BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies() will even pick up adhoc, random DLL's dropped into the /bin folder, even with no references to any projects in the Visual Studio solution. So it appears far more reliable than `AppDomain.Current.GetAssemblies()`.

I've rewritten my Assembly locator code to the following:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Compilation;

public static class AssemblyLocator
{
    private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Assembly> AllAssemblies;
    private static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Assembly> BinAssemblies;

    static AssemblyLocator()
    {
        AllAssemblies = new ReadOnlyCollection<Assembly>(
            BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().ToList());

        IList<Assembly> binAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();

        string binFolder = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "bin\\";
        IList<string> dllFiles = Directory.GetFiles(binFolder, "*.dll",
            SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();

        foreach (string dllFile in dllFiles)
        {
            AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dllFile);

            Assembly locatedAssembly = AllAssemblies.FirstOrDefault(a =>
                AssemblyName.ReferenceMatchesDefinition(
                    a.GetName(), assemblyName));

            if (locatedAssembly != null)
            {
                binAssemblies.Add(locatedAssembly);
            }
        }

        BinAssemblies = new ReadOnlyCollection<Assembly>(binAssemblies);
    }

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        return AllAssemblies;
    }

    public static ReadOnlyCollection<Assembly> GetBinFolderAssemblies()
    {
        return BinAssemblies;
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran into this problem and used your solution. Vote up! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been stuck on this issue too. You save my time.

Comment: good option, but trying to use this in a unit test you'll get this exception "This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase."

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you solved your own problem.

Edit: Personally, I would actually enumerate the assemblies, one by one, load them and look for the interface.  Do it based of files rather than what the AppDomain is doing.

Comment: Do you mean the last code sample MyApp.MissingAssembly.SomeClass  etc? If so, it's not really a solution, I'd have to keep adding dummy calls to different Assemblies before Bootstrapper.Run().

Comment: I think he means that you should walk through the files, explicitly loading them. Then you won't depend on whether or not you happened to have loaded it in a call.