# Why can I not register one class for multiple interfaces in Windsor?

Tags: c#, reflection, castle-windsor

I am trying to register all classes that implement my `IProcess<T1, T2>` interface with Windsor.  To accomplish this I have the following code in my installer:

```
        // Register all implemented process interfaces
        var procTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                                 .GetAssemblies()
                                 .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                                 .Where(x => x.IsDerivedFromOpenGenericType(typeof(IProcess<,>)))
                                 .ToList();

        foreach (var procType in procTypes)
            foreach (var procInterface in procType.GetInterfaces().Where(x => x.IsDerivedFromOpenGenericType(typeof(IProcess<,>))))
                container.Register(Component.For(procInterface).ImplementedBy(procType).LifeStyle.Transient);
```

One of the classes I a trying to register is the following:

```
public class PositionProcesses 
    : IProcess<CreatePositionParams, PositionDisplayViewModel>,
      IProcess<EditPositionParams, PositionDisplayViewModel>
{
}
```

The first interface gets registered correctly, but upon registering the second interface to be implemented by this class, I am getting the following error:

```
Test method MyJobLeads.Tests.Controllers.PositionControllerTests.Windsor_Can_Resolve_PositionController_Dependencies threw exception: 
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentRegistrationException: There is a component already registered for the given key MyJobLeads.DomainModel.Processes.Positions.PositionProcesses
```

on the first loop iteration my variables are:

```
+       procInterface   {Name = "IProcess`2" FullName = "MyJobLeads.DomainModel.Data.IProcess`2[[MyJobLeads.DomainModel.ProcessParams.Positions.CreatePositionParams, MyJobLeads.DomainModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[MyJobLeads.DomainModel.ViewModels.Positions.PositionDisplayViewModel, MyJobLeads.DomainModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}   System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
+       procType    {Name = "PositionProcesses" FullName = "MyJobLeads.DomainModel.Processes.Positions.PositionProcesses"}  System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

on the second:

```
+       procInterface   {Name = "IProcess`2" FullName = "MyJobLeads.DomainModel.Data.IProcess`2[[MyJobLeads.DomainModel.ProcessParams.Positions.EditPositionParams, MyJobLeads.DomainModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[MyJobLeads.DomainModel.ViewModels.Positions.PositionDisplayViewModel, MyJobLeads.DomainModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
+       procType    {Name = "PositionProcesses" FullName = "MyJobLeads.DomainModel.Processes.Positions.PositionProcesses"}  System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

(both of those are from the VS debugger.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use convention based component registration

```
BasedOnDescriptor processes = AllTypes.FromAssembly(assemblyWithProcesses)
    .BasedOn(typeof (IProcess<,>))
    .WithService.AllInterfaces()
    .Configure(x => x.LifeStyle.Transient);

container.Register(processes)
```

**EDIT** removed first sample as mentioned by @Krzysztof-kozmic

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that override.  Worked like a charm, thanks :)

Comment: I had to reread this a couple times to understand the difference from the OP's code.  You're passing the interfaces array all at once to `For`, rather than one interface at a time.  I will leave my answer, but I like this better because Windsor handles the naming for you :)

Comment: Added convention based registration example

Comment: @KallDrexx: It is a little hazardous to trust that the assemblies you want are actually loaded.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552223/.  You can configure Windsor to find installers via your config file, so it probably wouldn't hurt to tighten up your type selection a bit (ala hazzik's convention based registration example)

Comment: I suggest removing the first code sample and stick just to the updated one.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single component registered for multiple services, I think you'll have to name each registration manually.

See: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#Configuring_registration_13

```
container.Register(
    Component.For(procInterface)
             .ImplementedBy(procType)
             .LifeStyle.Transient
             .Named(component.Implementation.FullName
                 + "-"
                 + procInterface.Name)
    );
```

This should register each component by the type's full name *plus* the interface you're registering it for.

Comment: This option should work, but [I like hazzik's answer better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218885/why-can-i-not-register-one-class-for-multiple-interfaces-in-windsor/7218994#7218994).