# Unity registration fails after iisreset

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, asp.net-web-api

I am registering a load of dependencies like so.

```
container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
WithName.Default,
overwriteExistingMappings: true);
```

This registers things fine and the web api endpoints are properly configured.
If I do `iisreset` or simply wait for a bit then things fail with

The error message is not terribly helpful

```
"exceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ApiController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
```

Which of course the controller does not, and should not, have.

I am not sure what is going on... but if I register the dependencies explicitly

```
 container.RegisterType<IDoAThing, Domain.Things.DoAThing>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Then it all works.

How can I get the 'by convention' registration to keep working?

Comment: Maybe the assemblies have not been loaded yet into the app domain after iisreset by the time your Unity registration kicks in. Try getting the referenced assemblies with [`BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getreferencedassemblies.aspx) method to obtain a list of assemblies in the bin folder and pass this collection to the AllClasses.FromAssemblies helper method. Worst case you could use a well-known class from each of your assemblies, then register classes in those assemblies.

Comment: See a similar issue where the assemblies were not yet loaded in the app domain [here for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552223/asp-net-appdomain-currentdomain-getassemblies-assemblies-missing-after-app)

Comment: I have not got it working yet, but this looks likely. If you made it an answer I would upvote you for sweet sweet internet points!

Comment: Glad to see it helped, hopefully it will help you fixing the issue. I suspected this was the issue because I had a similar issue in the past but I couldn't really try it yesterday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like after the `iisreset`, the assemblies have not been loaded yet into the app domain by the time your Unity registration kicks in.

Since you are using the helper method `AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies()`, it will not register classes in assemblies that were not yet loaded.

Try getting the referenced assemblies with [`BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getreferencedassemblies.aspx), which will obtain a list of assemblies in the bin folder. Then perform your Unity registrations using those assemblies and the `AllClasses.FromAssemblies` helper method.

```
.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromAssemblies(
             BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>()),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default,
    overwriteExistingMappings: true);
```

In the worst case you could use a well-known class from each of your assemblies, getting its assembly via reflection and use it for your registration as in this simplified sample:

```
.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromAssemblies(typeof(Foo).Assembly),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default,
    overwriteExistingMappings: true);
```