# Compiled Class in Two Locations

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, compilation, viewstate

I'm a tad stuck trying to get a List to load from the ViewState using ASP.NET 4 and VB.NET. When I try to retrieve a collection using:

```
Public Property ItemsForImport As List(Of ImportItem)
    Get
        Return IIf(ViewState("ItemsForImport") Is Nothing, New List(Of ImportItem), CType(ViewState("ItemsForImport"), List(Of ImportItem)))
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of ImportItem))
        ViewState("ItemsForImport") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I get the exception:

```
[A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ImportItem] cannot be cast to [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ImportItem]. 
Type A originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. 
Type B originates from 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location     'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
```

Debugging shows that the collection is not null and contains 2 items. The class is only defined once and I've cleaned my temporary files from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

Generally I sometimes see this (I assume everyone does) when making rapid changes while debugging, but it goes after a couple of refreshes. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you try using DirectCast instead of CType?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your project folders. You probably have a duplicate assembly referenced somewhere in the solution, which is causing a conflict. Do you have a parent project that references the same assembly?

Read through a few of these solutions to see if anything fits your problem:

[InvalidCastException for two Objects of the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500280/invalidcastexception-for-two-objects-of-the-same-type)

[ASP.NET unloading assemblies in the bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078631/asp-net-unloading-assemblies-in-the-bin)

[Error Rendering control - [A] cannot be cast to [B] in the context LoadNeither](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838568/error-rendering-control-a-cannot-be-cast-to-b-in-the-context-loadneither)

Comment: Interestingly, I'm using a class with a Serializable attribute. If I store it in the HttpContext's session instead of the page ViewState, the page seems to go away.